# How to detect excel assembly (version) and use it programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, interop, xlsx

I needed my application to export a dataGridView content to Excel. That's fine, all the help ended up by adding the Excel.Interop reference according to the installed version of Excel, then creating a new Excel Application and finally saving to a file (.xlsx).

However, it worked fine on machines with the same installed version of Office (Excel 2013). But, on machines with either 2007 or 2016 it does not work.

I know how to check which version is installed, but is there a way to detect and use the Interop no matter which version is installed? For example adding the DLL reference during runtime.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you even try to google this? Hard to miss... check the registry for the version and program against an interface would be the solution

Comment: Ugh. Excel Interop. Is there a particular reason you're not going for a simpler and more widely compatible route such as using a library like EPPlus to form an xlsx file directly?

Comment: @CaiusJard I found NPOI. Which is better? EEPlus or NPOI?

Comment: @Sievajet I did some Google search and still looking. However, as I said I know how to check the version, I'm more interested on how to reference the assambly manually during runtime. I will try with your recommendation by using an interface.

Comment: Is there a reason why you’re using the interop for this? There are better ways without supporting every possible installed version of excel...

Comment: "Better" is subjective, SO is not for subjective questions. I mentioned EPPlus because I've used it, and found it easy to work with

Comment: Ok you both, you converted me, I will go for an independent and free DLL. Thank you